# two difficult conditions for subsetting in R

Tags: r, subset

I need to subset a df with two very difficult conditions to code (for me) in R:

Given the following dataframe:

```
A=as.factor(rep(1:50,3))
B=as.factor(rep(c(1,2,3),50))
C=(rep(rnorm(10,30,3),15)) 
df=data.frame(A,B,C)
```

I need to subset rows of that dataframe which, for a given level of a factor A, contains observations of two of the levels from B (ex, the level "1" and the level "2").

Any hint?
Thanks in advance
Agus

Comment: See if something like `df[df$A %in% 1 & df$B %in% c(1, 2), ]` helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want first level of factor A and first 2 levels of factor B

```
df[df$A %in% levels(df$A)[1] & df$B %in% levels(df$B)[1:2], ]
```

To change the subset, replace levels(df$A)[1] and levels(df$B)[1:2] by exact values you need.